# magazine purchases in software center

Tags: appcenter

I have a new install of elementary, and I notice that searches in software center give results for purchasing magazines and other things which I have 0 interest in.

Since I will NEVER buy magazines through software center, how can I turn off these results?

Thanks

*EDIT* the best solution for me was to install the Synaptic Package Manager

Comment: btw I don't see any free magazine in SC, though it is mentioned __free__ at left side, you have only Buy option.

Comment: Sins the software center is ubuntu's software center. elementary developers can't change it.  The next release will hopefully have our own app store :)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, it is possible to disable only magazines but it requires a lot more hacks.

The better choice is to use synaptic.

Installation:

Open terminal and run-

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

Comment: I appreciate the info, but it's not really the solution I'm looking for - I have no issue with paid software showing in search results when I'm looking for software, but I'll never be looking for magazines.

Comment: @emjaySX I think, I misinterpreted your question. Will you please clarify "purchasing magazines and other things" :)